# Pulling log messages for a particular log in systemd journal?

Tags: systemd, c, journaling

I was wondering if it is possible to pull log messages for a particular log with systemd's journal logging. For example, when I open a log in C, `openlog('slog', LOG_CONS | LOG_PID, LOG_LOCAL1)`, to pull just messages logged under '`slog`' or `LOCAL1`?

When I do something like `journalctl -u slog` or `journalctl -u LOG_LOCAL1`, it just tells me when the log begins and ends, not the actual log messages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but you passed the wrong switch to `journalctl`.

According to [journalctl(1)](http://0pointer.de/public/systemd-man/journalctl.html#-t) man page:

- To read messages with a given syslog identifier (say, "foo"), issue `journalctl -t foo` or `journalctl SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=foo`;
- To read messages with a given syslog facility, issue `journalctl SYSLOG_FACILITY=1` (note that facilities are stored and matched using their numeric values).

More generally, the syslog identifier and facility are stored in the journal as separate fields (`SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER` and `SYSLOG_FACILITY`). If you ever need to access the journal from, say, the C API, you will have to add matches on these fields directly.

The `journalctl -u` switch is used to add a match on the name of a systemd unit which owned the process which has generated the message. So this is the wrong switch to use.

Comment: Your identifier example with `foo`: Can I do something like `*foo*` for a specific syslog field?

Comment: @buhtz no — as far as I'm aware, journalctl cannot do glob matches.

Answer (score 5):

Right. That does it. Time to script around journalctl.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Provide a simple command-line interface for systemd "journalctl"
# See /usr/include/sys/syslog.h for syslog integer ids
# Example usage: "./syslog/bin/syslogga.sh --local0 --tail" to tail local0

set -o nounset

declare -a OPTIONS
declare -a MATCHES

OPTIONS=()
MATCHES=()

function processOptions {

   local UNKNOWN=
   local HELP=
   local SYSLOGSEL=0

   for P in "$@"; do

      if [[ $P == --kernel || $P == --kern || $P == -0 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=0")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --user || $P == -1 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=1")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --mail || $P == -2 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=2")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --daemon || $P == -3 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=3")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --auth || $P == -4 || $P == --selinux ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=4")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --syslog || $P == -5 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=5")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --lpr || $P == -6 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=6")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P =~ --news || $P == -7 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=7")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --uucp || $P == -8 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=8")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --cron || $P == -9 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=9")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --authpriv || $P == -10 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=10")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --ftp || $P == -11 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=11")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --local0 || $P == -16 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=16")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --local1 || $P == -17 ]]; then 
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=17")
         continue
      fi

      # In our system, local2 is sshd log
      if [[ $P == --local2 || $P == -18 || $P == --ssh ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=18")
         continue
      fi

      # In our system, local3 is pdns-recursor log
      if [[ $P == --local3 || $P == -19 || $P == --dns ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=19")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --local4 || $P == -20 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=20")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --local5 || $P == -21 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=21")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --local6 || $P == -22 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=22")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P == --local7 || $P == -23 ]]; then
         (( SYSLOGSEL += 1 )); if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then break; fi 
         MATCHES+=("SYSLOG_FACILITY=23")
         continue
      fi

      # Additional options

      if [[ $P =~ ^(--tail|-t|--follow|-f) ]]; then
         OPTIONS+=("--follow") # yup, "journalctl" uses "follow" instead of "tail"
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P =~ ^(--pager-end|-e|--bottom|--btm|--end) ]]; then
         OPTIONS+=("--pager-end")
         continue
      fi

      if [[ $P =~ ^(--help|-h) ]]; then
         HELP=1
         break
      fi

      # if we are here, we encountered something unknown in P
      # if UNKNOWN is already set, add a comma for separation

      if [[ -n $UNKNOWN ]]; then
         UNKNOWN="$UNKNOWN,"
      fi

      UNKNOWN="${UNKNOWN}${P}"

   done

   if [[ $SYSLOGSEL -gt 1 ]]; then
       echo "More than one facility selected" >&2
       HELP=1
   fi

   if [[ -n $UNKNOWN ]]; then
      echo "Unknown parameters '$UNKNOWN'" >&2
      HELP=1
   fi

   if [[ -n $HELP ]]; then
      # Only in our setup:
      SPECIAL_16
      cat >&2 <<HERE
Facilities:
--kern[el] , -0
--user     , -1
--mail     , -2
--daemon   , -3
--auth     , -4 , --selinux
--syslog   , -5
--lpr      , -6
--news     , -7
--uucp     , -8
--cron     , -9
--authpriv , -10
--ftp      , -11
--local0   , -16 
--local1   , -17
--local2   , -18 , --ssh
--local3   , -19 , --dns
--local4   , -20
--local5   , -21
--local6   , -22
--local7   , -23
Options:
--tail , --follow , -t , -f
--pager-end, --btm, --bottom, --end, -e
HERE
      exit 1
   fi

}

processOptions "$@"

declare -a ALL

ALL=()

if [[ -n ${OPTIONS[@]:-""} ]]; then
   ALL+=(${OPTIONS[@]})
fi

if [[ -n ${MATCHES[@]:-""} ]]; then
   ALL+=(${MATCHES[@]})
fi

if [[ -n ${ALL[@]:-""} ]]; then

   echo Running journalctl "${ALL[@]}" >&2

   journalctl "${ALL[@]}"

else 

   echo "Nothing set"

fi
```

Comment: Another thing systemd fails to do properly, great. m(

Comment: @stefanct May I ask you, what do you mean by "properly"? There is no established standard for naming command line arguments, hence your commentary sounds like groundless bashing.

Comment: This has not much to do with the naming but the *availability* of options. Apparently, `journalctl` does not natively allow to filter for standard facility names, which *are* standardized in POSIX btw, so that one has to rely on ridiculous workarounds like creating another mapping between those names and respective constants as the script above. Just another instance where systemd people ignore POSIX and become astonished when they get criticized for that...